# NetworkX node attribute drawing

Tags: attributes, draw, networkx

Im using networkx for visualization. I see when I use the function 
draw_networkx_edge_labels 
I can retrieve the labels for edges.

I want to print the attribute on node ( instead of the label).. try everything almost . still stuck. If i have 5 attributes per node, is there anyway I can print a specific attribute on each node ? For example, if a car node has attributes: size, price, company, .. I want to print the size of the car on each node ?

Don't know whether can output this on graph.

Comment: if you want to draw with pygraphviz instead see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67442702/1601580 since drawing with nx is not recommended that might be better (see networkx docs).

Answer (score 43):

You can do it by specifying the labels= keyword

```
import pylab
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node('Golf',size='small')
G.add_node('Hummer',size='huge')
G.add_edge('Golf','Hummer')
labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'size') 
nx.draw(G,labels=labels,node_size=1000)
pylab.show()
```

Comment: A somewhat easier replacement for line 7: `labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'size')`  That function returns a dict like the one created in line 7.

Comment: how about if i want to draw all attributes of all nodes in the drawing?

Comment: code suggested gives me this error: `networkx.exception.NetworkXError: random_state_index is incorrect`, what does it give you?