# Display a .png image from python on mint-15 linux

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, pygraphviz

I am trying to display a `.png` file I constructed using the following.

```
import pydot, StringIO
dot_data = StringIO.StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz( clf, out_file = dot_data,    
feature_names =['age', 'sex', 'first_class', 'second_class', 'third_class'])
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data( dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_png('titanic.png') 
from IPython.core.display import Image
Image( filename ='titanic.png')
```

I tried the following but neither errors nor `.png` are displayed:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open("titanic.png")
image.show()
```

Answer (score 19):

if you just want to display it, you may use `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread('file-name.png')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks behzad.nouri, but, all I get is a black screen <module 'DtreeObj2' from 'DtreeObj2.py'>
>>> DtreeObj2.construct()
>>>  ... no import errors or other, just no picture I have image viewer resident and that is what opens my .prn when I manually click on it.

Comment: `plt.show()` is missing after `plt.imshow( img )`. Otherwise the pop-up window will not show.