# Graphviz vs PyGraphViz

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I have some dot files (digraphs) that I need to read in Python and extract some values from the nodes to populate my data structure. I see there are two graphviz packages for Python: [graphviz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) and [pygraphviz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygraphviz). Is there any big difference between the two? From a quick scroll of the docs, they pretty much seem to do the same thing. I'll be using this in Python 2.7.X for the aforementioned task.

Comment: perhaps useful too: https://qr.ae/pGtb7r

Comment: perhaps also useful: https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/346 and https://python.libhunt.com/compare-pydot-vs-pygraphviz and https://github.com/pydot/pydot/issues/262

Comment: I don't understand, why does pygraphviz and graphviz BOTH exist as python packages? What is pygraphviz doing that graphviz didn't already do? why would I choose pygraphviz vs graphviz for python?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*graphviz* is a lightweight library which calls graphviz as a subprocess to execute all actions and produce output. This library is great as a quick and easy way to produce SVG or PNG output.

*pygraphviz* contains complete C bindings which uses graphviz as a library and expose all of graphviz's internal functionality like add/remove nodes/edges. But it comes with higher complexity in deployment as pip needs to compile C bindings and find all libraries.

In your case, as you need to read and manipulate dot files, it looks like you have to go with *pygraphviz*. Other interesting alternative to take a look is http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot which is a pure python dot parser.

Disclaimer: I am biased, because I contributed (a little bit) to pygraphviz.

Comment: You may want to add a note for Anaconda users: `conda install graphviz` will install the graphviz command line tools (including `dot`), *not* the Python `graphviz` library. If you want the `graphviz` Python library, you must run `conda install python-graphviz`, which will also install the graphviz command line tools (and for the `pygraphviz` library, just run `conda install pygraphviz`).

Comment: what about pygraphviz vs pydot?

Comment: I don't understand, why does pygraphviz and graphviz BOTH exist as python packages? What is pygraphviz doing that graphviz didn't already do? why would I choose pygraphviz vs graphviz for python?

Comment: @CharlieParker I think both are solving essentially same problem via different approaches. `graphviz` is pure python library for "dot file" manipulation and uses graphviz engine for rendering, `pygraphviz` is a wrapper on top of graphviz C library and uses graphviz for manipulating underlying object model as well. It passed 5 years since the original answer, and it looks like by now pretty much parity between packages was reached. I recommend to go with pure python `graphviz` as deployment without need to compile c bindings is so much easier.