# Simplify networkx node labels

Tags: python, networkx

```
%matplotlib inline
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('abc@gmail.com')
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

The output figure is

[image]

What I want is

[image]

I have thousands of email records from person@email.com to another@email.com in a csv file, I use `G.add_node(email_address)` and `G.add_edge(from, to)` to build G. I want keep the whole email address in Graph G but display it in a simplified string.

Comment: why don't you just add `G.add_node('abc')`?

Comment: In fact the second fig generated as you say, but I have many email address in a csv file and I want to save more information in the figure.

Comment: you need to process those, loop over the email addresses, split the string using `@` and take only the left part of the email address

Comment: Can I do it with networkx instead of string method?

Comment: Put that in the question as being a prerequisite

Comment: take a look at the second part of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28533293/2966723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`networkx` has a method called [`relabel_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html#networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes) that takes a graph (`G`), a `mapping` (the relabeling rules) and returns a new graph (`new_G`) with the nodes relabeled.

That said, in your case:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('abc@gmail.com')
mapping = {
   'abc@gmail.com': 'abc'
}
relabeled_G = nx.relabel_nodes(G,mapping)
nx.draw(relabeled_G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

That way you keep `G` intact and haves simplified labels.

You can optionally modify the labels in place, without having a new copy, in which case you'd simply call `G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping, copy=False)`

If you don't know the email addresses beforehand, you can pass `relabel_nodes` a function, like so:

```
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, lambda email: email.split("@")[0], copy=False)
```

Comment: I just finished my code only find that nx.relabel_nodes replace all node name in .gexf file, it work just like G.add_node('abc') and '@gmail.com' disappears totally