# Python networkx - How to draw graph with labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

```
from graphviz import *
import networkx as nx
from networkx import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_edge(1,2)
myLabels = {1: 'node1', 2: 'node2'}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, myLabels, 'label')
nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)
```

So current I use the latest networkx. When I use nx.draw(G, with_values=True), it uses the vertex indexes instead of labels.

How can I fix this? Thank you.

[image: Image should say node1, node2]

Comment: Look at the second half of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28533293/2966723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this command: `nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)` to `nx.draw(G,with_labels=True, labels = myLabels)`

Comment: Can myLabels have more keys than the number of nodes in G.nodes() ? For example, myLabels = {1:'x1', 2:'x2', 3:'x3'} while G only has 2 nodes. When I do this, it gives KeyError due to myLabels